# Función para convertir a números romanos en PHP

Tags: php

Esto es una pregunta/respuesta y una pregunta al mismo tiempo.

No sé si existe oficialmente una función nativa de PHP que sirva para convertir cualquier número entero en número romano.

Aportaré una función en auto-respuesta, con la idea de compartirla y de aceptar críticas sobre posibles fallos, o respuestas que presenten una función mejor o más completa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta es la función que uso para convertir a números romanos.

## <kbd>[**VER DEMO**](http://rextester.com/QCHK22204)</kbd>

## php

---

```
<?php 

    function a_romano($integer, $upcase = true) 
    {
        $table = array('M'=>1000, 'CM'=>900, 'D'=>500, 'CD'=>400, 'C'=>100, 
                       'XC'=>90, 'L'=>50, 'XL'=>40, 'X'=>10, 'IX'=>9,   
                       'V'=>5, 'IV'=>4, 'I'=>1);
        $return = '';
        while($integer > 0) 
        {
            foreach($table as $rom=>$arb) 
            {
                if($integer >= $arb)
                {
                    $integer -= $arb;
                    $return .= $rom;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }

/*Probando*/

echo a_romano(1).PHP_EOL;
echo a_romano(12).PHP_EOL;
echo a_romano(53).PHP_EOL;
echo a_romano(2017).PHP_EOL;    
?>
```

---

## resultado

```
I
XII
LIII
MMXVII
```

---

Ver: **[Numbers to Roman Numbers with php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15023547/5587982)**

Answer (score 2):

Encontré este código:

```
<?php
function romanNumber($numero){ 
    $miles = array("","M","MM","MMM");
    $centenas = array("","C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM");
    $decenas = array("","X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC");
    $unidades = array("","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX");
    $numero = str_split($numero);
    switch(count($numero)){
        case 1: 
            return $unidades[$numero[0]];
        break;
        case 2: 
            return $decenas[$numero[0]].$unidades[$numero[1]];          
        break;
        case 3:                         
            return $centenas[$numero[0]].$decenas[$numero[1]].$unidades[$numero[2]];
        break;
        case 4:                                         
            return $miles[$numero[0]].$centenas[$numero[1]].$decenas[$numero[2]]. $unidades[$numero[3]];
        break;
    }       
}
?>
```

Espero sea lo que buscas.

FUENTE: http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/codigos-reto-romanos-835322/

Comment: ¿dónde lo encontraste?

Comment: Gracias. Pero me gustó más la mía :)

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la siguiente función:

```
<?
//############################dec_romana ($numero,$case)################
//#
//#     - De decimal a numeración romana
//#
//#     case da la opción de representar el numero con símbolos
//#     en minúscula o mayúscula (xlvii ó XLVII). Será "l" para
//#     el primer caso y "u" para el segundo (lower, upper)
//#####################################################################

function dec_romana ($numero,$case)
{
    $simbolos=array("I","V","X","L","C","D","M");
    $valores=array ("1","5","10","50","100","500","1000","5000");
    if ($numero<=3999) {
        while ($numero>0)
        {
            $i=0;
            while ($i<7)
            {
                while ($numero>=$valores[$i] && $numero<$valores[$i+1])
                {
                    $par=$i%2;  // paridad
                    if ($numero>=$valores[$i+1]-$valores[$i-$par])
                    {
                        $romano=$romano.$simbolos[$i-$par].$simbolos[$i+1];
                        $numero=$numero-($valores[$i+1]-$valores[$i-$par]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $romano=$romano.$simbolos[$i];
                        $numero=$numero-$valores[$i];
                    }
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
        if ($case=="l") $romano=strtolower ($romano);
    }
    else $romano="overflow";
    return $romano;
}

// Ejemplo de uso -->  
//echo $numero=dec_romana("2349","u");

?>
```

Fuente: http://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/PHP/644-Numeros-romanos.html

Comment: Gracias. Pero me gustó más la mía :)