# ¿Hay alguna forma de guardar una variable en otro lado que no sea en la BD en Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, mvc, poo

Estoy intentando algo medio loco. El caso de uso es que cada 2 años se cambia de Consejo Directivo entonces éste año va a cambiar al Consejo XXXVII (Actualmente está en el XXXVI). Se me hizo absurdo crear una tabla sólo para guardar el número de consejo entonces se me ocurrió guardar el número en una variable creada en el controlador y editarla con x-editable. Todo va bien excepto que no guarda la variable. He aquí mi código:

Código del Controlador

```
//Declaro la variable
protected $consejo;

// Inicializo la viariable para mandarla a la vista
public function editDirectors() 
{
    $numConsejo = $this->consejo;
    return view('board.edit_directors', compact('numConsejo'));

}
//Se supone que guardo la variable
public function uploadNumber(Request $request)
{
    $this->consejo = $request->value;
    $numConsejo = $this->consejo;
    return $numConsejo;
}
```

Código en el template

```
<a href="#" id="num-consejo" data-type="text" 
                                 data-pk="1" 
                                 data-url="{{url('/consejo-directivo/editar/numero-consejo')}}"
                                 data-value="{{$numConsejo}}" 
                                 data-name="numConsejo" 
                                 data-title="Número de Consejo Directivo">{{$numConsejo}}</a>
    Consejo Directivo</h3>
```

Inicializo el x-editable

```
//Se inicializa el x-editable para modificar el número del comité
$('#num-consejo').editable({
    error: function(response, newValue) 
    {
        if(response.status === 500) {
            return 'Parece que hubo un error al guardar. Favor de reportarlo a: udi_cime@hotmail.com';
        } else {
            return 'Parece que hubo un error al guardar. Favor de reportarlo a: udi_cime@hotmail.com';
        }
    }
});
```

Y la ruta

```
Route::put('/consejo-directivo/editar/numero-consejo' , 'DirectorController@uploadNumber');//Ruta para guardar el número de consejo
```

Estoy más que seguro que estoy guardando mal la variable pero no encuentro solución alguna porque ya hice debug en la consola y sí llega el Request al controlador y hace el return con el valor que ingresé en el x-editable pero al darle F5 no se guardó y cuando hago un var_dump() o dd() en el método editDirectors() me sale que es nula la variable $consejo.

Agredezco la ayuda y la atención si llegaste a leer hasta aquí :3

**Modificaciones**

Hice un archivo en la carpeta config para almacenar allí el valor (config/board.php) y le agregué el siguiente código:

```
return [
'director' => [
    'number' => 'XXXVI'
    ]
];
```

Seguido modifiqué el código del controlador:

```
//Aquí traigo el valor de config/board.php y lo mando al template, funciona :D
public function editDirectors() 
{
    $numConsejo = Config::get('board.director.number');
    return view('board.edit_directors', compact('directors', 'numConsejo'));
}

//Aquí se supone que guardo la variable en el archivo config/board.php pero no guarda :(
public function uploadNumber(Request $request)
{
    $numConsejo = $request->value;
    Config::set('board.director.number', $numConsejo);
    dd(Config::get('board.director.number'));
    //return $numConsejo;
}
```

Tuve que correr el comando:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Esto para que se pudiera visualizar el archivo config/board.php pero parece que cada que se modifica el valor de ese archivo necesito correr ese comando.

¿Alguna idea? Agradeceré mucho la ayuda :3

Comment: Tienes un error de concepto, la variable que intentas usar no tiene persistencia de datos. Yo sinceramente crearía un método para calcular el número que le corresponde desde la fecha de inicio, si no quieres utilizar la base de datos. Esto te puede ayudar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79193/funci%C3%B3n-para-convertir-a-n%C3%BAmeros-romanos-en-php

Comment: Me gustó muchísimo tu solución pero debo hacerlo editable ya que si fallece le presidente del comité, se cambia de consejo (de número). Igual hay otra opción que es guardar la variable en el archivo .env ó en config/filesystems.php

Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solución**

Me parece una mala práctica lo que hice pero cubre mi necesidad.

Tomado de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450162/how-to-set-env-values-in-laravel-programmatically-on-the-fly?answertab=active#tab-top

En el archivo .env agregué:

```
BOARD_NUMBER = XXXVI
```

Y éste es mi código:

```
//Mando a llamar al valor que tiene el BOARD_NUMBER en el .env y lo mando al template.
public function editDirectors() 
{
    $numConsejo = env('BOARD_NUMBER');
    return view('board.edit_directors', compact('directors', 'numConsejo'));
}

//Abro el archivo .env y sobreescribo el viejo valor con el nuevo
protected function uploadNumber(Request $request)
{
    $numConsejo = $request->value;
    $envFile = app()->environmentFilePath();
    $str = file_get_contents($envFile);

    $oldValue = env('BOARD_NUMBER');

    $str = str_replace("BOARD_NUMBER={$oldValue}", "BOARD_NUMBER={$numConsejo}\n", $str);

    $fp = fopen($envFile, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $str);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

En el mismo link hay otra solución donde se ejecuta el comando "php artisan config:cache" desde el mismo código pero dudo que me funcione debido a que subiré la aplicación a un servidor compartido.

Saludos y espero esto le sirva a alguien :)

Comment: no me parece mala practica lo de usar una variable en .ENV. Eso se hace para tratar valores que en principio no van a cambiar en mucho tiempo. Lo que pasa es que si lo cambias, todo lo que tengas en tu bbdd hara referencia al nuevo valor, con lo que parece que tendras que borrar la bbdd para que sea "coherente" lo que tienes... Yo si que crearia una tabla para guardar el valor, o en su defecto revisaria la bbdd para ver donde añadir ese valor.