# Mejorar el codigo java de Numeros Romanos

Tags: java

Hola buena me gustaría saber si mi programa se puede optimizar de alguna manera.

El ejercicio :

```
//10.- Programa que reciba un número y lo muestre en números Romanos del 1 al 3999
```

Mi programa:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package boletin;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author javie
 */
public class Romano {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n; //pongamos que n vale 3950
        System.out.print("Introduce el numero que te lo voy a comvertir a romano : ");
        n = teclado.nextInt();
        int miles, centenas, decenas, unidades;
        int resto = n; // resto vale 3950
        String resultado = "";

        miles = resto / 1000; //3950/1000=3
        resto = resto % 1000;  //950

        centenas = resto / 100; //9
        resto = resto % 100; // 50

        decenas = resto / 10; //5
        resto = resto % 10; // 0

        unidades = resto;

        for (int i = 1; i <= miles; i++) {
            resultado += "M";
        }
        switch (centenas) {
            case 1:
                resultado += "C";
                break;
            case 2:
                resultado += "CC";
                break;
            case 3:
                resultado += "CCC";
                break;
            case 4:
                resultado += "CD";
                break;
            case 5:
                resultado += "D";
                break;
            case 6:
                resultado += "DC";
                break;
            case 7:
                resultado += "DCC";
                break;
            case 8:
                resultado += "DCCC";
                break;
            case 9:
                resultado += "CM";
                break;
        }
        switch (decenas) {
            case 1:
                resultado += "X";
                break;
            case 2:
                resultado += "XX";
                break;
            case 3:
                resultado += "XXX";
                break;
            case 4:
                resultado += "XL";
                break;
            case 5:
                resultado += "L";
                break;
            case 6:
                resultado += "LX";
                break;
            case 7:
                resultado += "LXX";
                break;
            case 8:
                resultado += "LXXX";
                break;
            case 9:
                resultado += "XC";
                break;
        }
        switch (unidades) {
            case 1:
                resultado += "I";
                break;
            case 2:
                resultado += "II";
                break;
            case 3:
                resultado += "III";
                break;
            case 4:
                resultado += "IV";
                break;
            case 5:
                resultado += "V";
                break;
            case 6:
                resultado += "VI";
                break;
            case 7:
                resultado += "VII";
                break;
            case 8:
                resultado += "VIII";
                break;
            case 9:
                resultado += "IX";
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("El número " + n + " en números romanos es: " + resultado);
    }
}
```

Os lo agradecería mucho mi maestro me ha dicho que lo tengo bien pero que a ver si encuentro alguna optimizar utilizando por ejemplos array pero me estoy rompiendo la cabeza pero no caigo
El ejercicio : Programa que reciba un número y lo muestre en números Romanos del 1 al 3999.

Yo estare intentandolo tambien a la par de vosotros para ver como lo pudiera haber hecho muchas gracias adelantadas y un saludo.

Comment: Podrías usar [algo como esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/79194/29967). Es PHP, la conversión a Java sería simple, cambiando el array asociativo por un `Map`.

Comment: ya pero debe de ser en java es lo que estabamos dando

Comment: Lo sé. El código es simple, intenta pasarlo a Java y si tienes problemas lo dices y te ayudaremos a hacerlo funcionar. Puedes crear un `Map` u otro objeto para asociar cada letra, sería prácticamente lo único que cambiaría considerablemente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si por curiosidad quieres ver como quedaría lo que te sugirió A. Cedano en su comentario, aquí te dejo una implementación básica de cómo usar un Map para pasar los números a romano

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    
    public static Map map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Escribe un numero y te lo convierto a romano : ");
        int a=teclado.nextInt();
        populateMap();
        System.out.println(romanize(a));
    }
    
    
    public static String romanize(int value){
        String result = "";
        int number = value;
        while(number > 0){
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = it.next();
                if(number >= entry.getValue()){
                    number -= entry.getValue();
                    result += entry.getKey();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public static void populateMap(){
        map.put("M", 1000);
        map.put("CM", 900);
        map.put("D", 500);
        map.put("CD", 400);
        map.put("C", 100);
        map.put("XC", 90);
        map.put("L", 50);
        map.put("XL", 40);
        map.put("X", 10);
        map.put("IX", 9);
        map.put("V", 5);
        map.put("IV", 4);
        map.put("I", 1);
    }
}
```

Funciona con cualquier número.

Comment: pues seria mucho mejor la verdad

Comment: pero si yo quiero pasarlo como un scanner como lo hago

Comment: esta mal porque por ejemplo si pones 30 o 35 se queda pillado

Comment: Efectivamente, @JavierG.Raya se me había olvidado resetear el iterador del mapa en cada entrada al bucle for, ahora ya funciona correctamente! Disculpa, las prisas no son buenas :)

Comment: no pasa nada lo voy a mirrar

Comment: si me permite le he echo una mejora te la voy a sugerir a ver como la ves

Comment: ya te lo edite a ver si lo vez mejor asi

Answer (score 0):

Listo encontre una manera muy simple seria asi

```
package boletin;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author javie
 */
public class RomanoV2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        String unidad[] = {"", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"}; //Declaro un array el cual pongo los numero romano los cuales voy a usar
        String decena[] = {"", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC"};
        String centena[] = {"", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM"};
        String miles = "";

        System.out.print("Ingresa numero entre 1 y 3999 y te lo convierto a romanos: ");
        int n = teclado.nextInt();
        int resto = n;
        m = resto / 1000; //3950/1000=3
        resto = resto % 1000;  //950

        int c = resto / 100; //9
        resto = resto % 100; // 50

        int d = resto / 10; //5
        resto = resto % 10; // 0

        int u = resto;
        for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
            miles += "M";
        }
        if (n >= 1000) {
            System.out.println(miles + centena[c] + decena[d] + unidad[u]);
        } else if (n >= 100) {
            System.out.println(centena[c] + decena[d] + unidad[u]);
        } else {
            if (n >= 10) {
                System.out.println(decena[d] + unidad[u]);
            } else {
                System.out.println(unidad[n]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1.Declaro un array el cual pongo los numero romano los cuales voy a usar.

2.Pongo un Scanner el cual captara el numero que voy a convertir a romano.

3.

```
  m = resto / 1000; //3950/1000=3
        resto = resto % 1000;  //950

        int c = resto / 100; //9
        resto = resto % 100; // 50

        int d = resto / 10; //5
        resto = resto % 10; // 0
```

Eso daría el resultado y se partiría en miles, centenas ,decenas y unidades

Hago un if el cual compruebo si es mayor de 1000 imprimo
`System.out.println(miles + centena[c] + decena[d] + unidad[u]);`
y eso seria todo creo que no me deje nada